# change the class for the first row extend from mysql with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a banner that used from bootstrap and, the first slider on this banner should have `class='item active'` the rest of the sliders should have `class='item'` I am getting my sliders from my database

so far that what I try to do.

```
<?php
        $getBanner = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM banner_english");
        if ($getBanner->execute()) {
            $results = $getBanner->get_result();
            while ($b = $results->fetch_array()) {
                $bannerImages = array($b['image']);
                foreach ($bannerImages as $image) {
                    if ($image[0]) {
                        echo '<div class="item active">
                    <img src="../images/en_banner/' . $image . '" alt="Koueider">
                </div>';
                    } else {
                        echo '<div class="item">
                    <img src="../images/en_banner/' . $image . '" alt="Koueider">
                </div>';
                        var_dump($bannerImages);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
```

still not working as expected

```
var_dump
array (size=1)
  0 => string '06.jpg' (length=6)
array (size=1)
  0 => string '03.jpg' (length=6)
```

I see that the `var_dump` is `0` for all items what did I do wrong here?

Comment: What does your banner_english table look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fix to the old code:

```
<?php
        $getBanner = $db->prepare("SELECT image FROM banner_english");
        if ($getBanner->execute()) {
            $results = $getBanner->get_result();
            $is_first = true;
            while ($b = $results->fetch_array()) {               
                    if ($is_first) {
                        echo '<div class="item active">
                    <img src="../images/en_banner/' . $b[0] . '" alt="Koueider">
                </div>';
                    $is_first = false;
                    } else {
                        echo '<div class="item">
                    <img src="../images/en_banner/' . $b[0] . '" alt="Koueider">
                </div>';
                        var_dump($bannerImages);
                    }
               }
          }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the code like this:

```
<?php
        $getBanner = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM banner_english");
        if ($getBanner->execute()) {
            $results = $getBanner->get_result();
            $rows = $results->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                $ind = 0;
                foreach ($rows as $image) {
                    if ($ind == 0) {
                        echo '<div class="item active">
                    <img src="../images/en_banner/' . $image . '" alt="Koueider">
                </div>';
                    $ind++;
                    } else {
                        echo '<div class="item">
                    <img src="../images/en_banner/' . $image . '" alt="Koueider">
                </div>';
                        var_dump($bannerImages);
                    }
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: I am getting `Notice: Array to string conversion` for var `$image`

Comment: O yeah, change to:

     foreach ($rows['image'] as $image) {

Comment: didn't solve the issue it says `Notice: Undefined index: image in` can't I print_r the `$image`?

Comment: Do you really need ALL the data from table? maybe instead of SELECT *, do SELECT image FROM....

Comment: you are right about this I changed it to `SELECT image` but still the same issue if for each is `foreach ($rows as $image) {` it's says `Notice: Array to string conversion` and if I changed to `foreach ($rows['image'] as $image) {` it says `Notice: Undefined index: image in`

Comment: can you do var_dump($rows) and tell me what it shows you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69992/discussion-between-yousef-altaf-and-yair-r).